# Collections with several constraints (time and size) in Java

Tags: java, collections

I have two processes (producer/consumer).  The first one puts elements in a Collection, the second one reads them.

I want the second process not to read every individual element, but wait until:

- There are at least N elements in the collection **OR**
- The last element was received T seconds ago.

Is there any Collection in Java 5+ that allows this kind of behaviour?  I was thinking about an implementation of [Queue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html), but I've only found DelayQueue that is not exactly what I need.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything like it in java collections, guava doesn't seem to have it too. Perhaps, it would be easier if you try doing it yourself on top of, let's say LinkedList, and ask here if you have any problems with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd implement an *observable collection*. The second process will listen to events, signalling that `N` elements are in the collection (events based on `size` attribute) and that no element has been added for a certain time (needs a timer, that is reset on every `add` operation)

Something like this (just drafting the *size* requirement):

```
public ObservableCollection implements Collection {

   private int sizetrigger;
   private Collection collection;
   private Collection<Listener> listeners = new ArrayList<Listener>();
   public ObservableCollection(Collection collection) {
     this.collection = collection;
   }

   @Override
   boolean add(Object element) {
     collection.add(element);
     if (size >= sizeTrigger) {
        fireSizeEvent();
     }
   }

   private fireSizeEvent() {
      for(Listener listener:listeners) {
         listener.thresholdReached(this);
      }
   }

   // addListener, removeListener and implementations of interface methods
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've also found http://commons.apache.org/dormant/events/apidocs/org/apache/commons/events/observable/ObservableCollection.html that could also be a good starting point.